# LWC HTML not rerendering after object change

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am facing a similar issue, where I need to modify the object. its not rerendering the HTML. Any thoughts on this ? I want to rerender UI after this object is modified.

I went throught the documents that track re-renders only properties and not modifications to objects.

I am using sectionList for UI rendering. When i invoke this on button click and arrays is modified, but the same is not re-rendering.

HTML :

```
<template for:each={sectionList} for:item='secDet'>
<button class="slds-button slds-section__title-action" value={secDet.sectionName} onclick={toggleSection}>
                            <lightning-icon icon-name={secDet.iconVar}  alternative-text="Warning!" variant="warning"></lightning-icon>
                        <span class="slds-truncate"> Account Name</span>
                </button>
</template>
```

JS:

```
@track sectionList;
toggleSection() {
for (let i = 0, len = this.sectionList.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (this.sectionList[i].iconVar == 'utility:chevronright') {
            this.sectionList[i].iconVar = 'utility:chevrondown';
            this.sectionList[i].fieldDisplayClass = 'slds-show';
        } else {
            this.sectionList[i].iconVar = 'utility:chevronright';
            this.sectionList[i].fieldDisplayClass = 'slds-hide';
        }
    }
    /*this.sectionList = this.sectionList.map((item) => {
        item.iconVar = item.iconVar === 'utility:chevronright' ? 'utility:chevrondown' : 'utility:chevronright';
        return item;
    });*/
    console.log('secTempList => ', JSON.stringify(this.sectionList));
```

}

Comment: Did you track your sectionList in your js code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I think you are tracking wrong variable.
2. You need `key` attribute for the first child in `iteration`.
3. You need to open/close only clicked item.
4. You can use modern javascript ES6 `find` to get the element.

Try to change code to:

HTML:

```
<template>
  <template for:each={sectionList} for:item='secDet'>
    <button key={secDet.sectionName} data-id={secDet.sectionName} class="slds-button slds-section__title-action"
            value={secDet.sectionName}
            onclick={toggleSection}>
      <lightning-icon icon-name={secDet.iconVar} alternative-text="Warning!" variant="warning"></lightning-icon>
      <span class="slds-truncate"> Account Name</span>
    </button>
  </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```
@track sectionList;
toggleSection(event) {
    let clickedSec = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    let clickedItem = this.sectionList.find((item) => item.sectionName === clickedSec);
    clickedItem.iconVar = clickedItem.iconVar === 'utility:chevronright' ? 'utility:chevrondown' : 'utility:chevronright';
    console.log('sectionList => ', JSON.stringify(this.sectionList));
}
```

Comment: I tried with maps and for loop , i didnt get the console statement printed. But my question is will it rerender UI automatically when we change the object like this ? Just like Aura components ?

Comment: yes it will rerender provided you are modifying tracked objects/arrays. LWC is much better than AURA in terms of rerendering. AURA would not know when an inner property is changed but LWC will know it.

Comment: you should invoke `toggleSection`

Comment: Yeah , i am invoking that method on button click. I just re-edited the question. Not sure where to post the updated code.

Comment: in question itself you can show HTML also

Comment: Added html as well

Comment: added correct answer

Comment: Pls mark solved if solved