# LWC HTML not rerendering after object change NOT Solved

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events, track

I am having a similar issue as the one linked at the bottom, it looks like the answers are claimed to work, however I cannot seem to figure out wth is wrong with my code that seems to be very similar.  The key to this code is the Select All checkbox should check and uncheck the child order cards. please ignore the wireData field, it is used in other code not included here.

Here is the code:

**child html**

```
<template>
<button slot="actions"
title={title}
class={checkStyle}
onclick={clickHandler}
>
<lightning-icon icon-name={checkIcon} alternative-text={title} variant={iconVariant} size="xx-small" class="slds-button__icon check" onclick={clickHandler}></lightning-icon>
</button>    
</template>
```

**child js**

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class Child extends LightningElement {
@api title;
@api isChecked = false;
@api checkedIcon = "utility:check";
@api checkedVariant = "inverse";
@api uncheckedIcon = "";
@api uncheckedVariant = "";

checkStyle = "slds-button checkbox checkbox-base";
checkIcon = this.uncheckedIcon;
iconVariant = this.uncheckedVariant;
isRendered = false;

clickHandler = (event) => {
    this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;

    let styles = "slds-button checkbox ";
    this.checkStyle = (this.isChecked ? styles + "checkbox-brand" : styles + "checkbox-base");
    this.checkIcon = (this.isChecked ? "utility:check" : "");
    this.iconVariant = (this.isChecked ? "inverse" : "");

    let realData = {
        checked: this.isChecked
    };

    fireCustomEvent(this, 'checkchanged', realData);       
};

fireCustomEvent(component, customEventName, eventValue) {
let customChange = new CustomEvent(customEventName, {
    detail: eventValue,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});

component.dispatchEvent(customChange);
}

//Page lifecycle events
renderedCallback() {
    if(!this.isRendered) {
        this.isRendered = true;
        this.checkStyle = (this.isChecked ? "slds-button checkbox checkbox-brand" : "slds-button checkbox checkbox-base");
        this.checkIcon = (this.isChecked ? this.checkedIcon : this.uncheckedIcon);
        this.iconVariant = (this.isChecked ? this.checkedVariant : this.uncheckedVariant);        
    }
}
}
```

**for completeness child css**

```
.checkbox {
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
padding-left: 2px;
}

.checkbox-brand {
border-color: #025eb1;
background: #025eb1;
}

.checkbox-base {
border-color: rgb(186, 186, 186);
background: white;
}

.check {
margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

**parent html**

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Orders" icon-name="utility:ad_set">
    <div class="slds-card__body_inner">
        <template if:true={wireData}>
            <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" pull-to-boundary="small">
                <template for:each={orderList} for:item="item">
                    <lightning-layout-item key={item.id} size="3" class="slds-var-p-around_x-small">
                        <!-- Start bear tile -->
                        <lightning-card class="order-tile">
                            <div slot="title" class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                                <div class="slds-media__figure">
                                    <lightning-icon icon-name="custom:custom42" size="small" class="order-icon"></lightning-icon>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-media__body slds-truncate">
                                    <h2>
                                        <span class="slds-text-heading_small">
                                            {item.order.OrderNumber}
                                        </span>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <c-child data-id={item.id} title="select" is-checked={item.checked} class="order-checkbox" slot="actions"></c-child>

                            <div class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small order-tile-body">
                                <div class="slds-media">
                                    <div class="slds-media__body">
                                        <p class="slds-var-m-bottom_xx-small">{item.order.Client}</p>
                                        <p class="slds-var-m-bottom_xx-small">${item.order.TotalAmount}</p>
                                        <p class="slds-var-m-bottom_xx-small">{item.order.Quantity} acres</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </lightning-card>
                        <!-- End bear tile -->
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </template>
            </lightning-layout>
        </template>
        <template if:true={error}>
            <div class="slds-text-color_error">
                An error occurred while loading the order list
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
    <div slot="footer" class="slds-docked-form-footer">
        <div style="width:50%; padding-left: 10px;">
            <div class="slds-float_left">
                <c-child title="Select all" is-checked="true" class="select-all" oncheckchanged={checkChangedHandler}></c-child>
            
                <span style="padding-left: 5px;">Select all</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div style="width:50%">
            <button 
                title="Send to 3PL" 
                class="slds-button slds-button_neutral slds-button_icon-inverse slds-float_left send-button">
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:merge" alternative-text="Send to 3PL" variant="inverse" size="xx-small" class="slds-button__icon_left"></lightning-icon>
                Send to 3PL
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

**parent js**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';

const OrderWrapper = {
id : '',
checked : false,
order : {}
};

export default class App extends LightningElement {
@track wireData;
@track orderList = [];
filters = "";

connectedCallback() {
    let o = Object.create(OrderWrapper);
    o.id = 'xxxxxxxx';
    o.checked = true;
    o.order = { OrderNumber:'000001', Client:'Test Farm', TotalAmount: 9.99, Quantity:10 };
    this.orderList.push(o);
    this.wireData = this.orderList;
}

checkChangedHandler = (event) => {
    if(event && event.detail) {
        this.orderList.forEach((o) => { 
            o.checked = event.detail.checked;
        });
    }
};
}
```

for completeness parent css

```
.order-tile {
border: 1px solid #d2955d;
border-radius: .25rem;
display: block;
}

.order-icon {
background: #484ba1;
}

.send-button {
background: #02a377;
border-color: #02a377;
height: 30px;
}
```

Seems to be same as this post, but my code does not cause UI rerender:
[LWC HTML not rerendering after object change](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272293/lwc-html-not-rerendering-after-object-change?newreg=127c83565fb446a69054e1b8e9df8c3b)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the following errors:

> `HTMLBridgeElement` constructor can’t read the value of property `uncheckedVariant` because the owner component hasn’t set the value yet. Instead, use the `HTMLBridgeElement` constructor to set a default value for the property.

> `HTMLBridgeElement` constructor can’t read the value of property `uncheckedIcon` because the owner component hasn’t set the value yet. Instead, use the `HTMLBridgeElement` constructor to set a default value for the property.

You cannot reference `@api` member variable values until the parent has set them, use `connectedCallback` to initialize these values.

e.g.,

```js
class Child extends LightningComponent {
  @api uncheckedIcon = "";
  @api uncheckedVariant = "";

  checkIcon;
  iconVariant;

  connectedCallback(){
    this.checkIcon = this.uncheckedIcon;
    this.iconVariant = this.uncheckedVariant;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I refactored the code to use the connectedCallback as you show and I see no errors are occurring now, however the parent UI is still not updating based on the checked state of the Select All checkbox child.